# How to show two tables together with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, codeigniter-2

How do I show two tables together with CodeIgniter?

I tried many times, but I can not do it. I tried to search using Google and YouTube, but I can not. How can I do it?

I have two tables:

#### Table 1:

```
id  image  title
1   1.jpg  pic1
2   2.jpg  pic2
3   3.jpg  pic3
8   8.jpg  pic8
```

#### Table 2:

```
id2  image2  title2
4   p1.jpg  img1
5   p2.jpg  img2
6   p3.jpg  img3
```

And I want the result:

```
- 1.jpg  pic1
- p1.jpg  img1

- 2.jpg  pic2
- p2.jpg  img2

- 3.jpg  pic3
- p3.jpg  img3

-8.jpg  pic8
```

Comment: You can look at using codeigniter query builder join http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON(table2.image2 = CONCAT('p',table1.image))";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->image . " ". $row->title . "<br>";
    echo $row->image2 . " ". $row->title2 . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: But some time My ID table1 and 2 different prograhammer did u have other way for me help me please :(

Comment: And make sure you add an index for "image" columns, so query will perform faster.

Comment: thz q prograhammer :D

Comment: Hi prograhammer did u have facebook acc or email ?

Comment: Yeah you can email me at  prograhammer at gmail.com

Comment: prograhammer@gmail.com ?

Comment: wait I craete exple for u

Comment: Hi prograhammer I have sent the attacment to you .

Answer (score 0):

Join two tables:

```
$this->query("SELECT
                 `product_master`.`id`,
                 `product_master`.`prod_style`,
                 `product_master`.`prod_name`,
                 `product_attributes`.`id`,
                 `product_attributes`.`prod_style`,
                 `product_attributes`.` prod_attr`,
                 `product_attributes`.`prod_value`
             FROM
                 `product_attributes`,
                 `product_master`");
```

Comment: but some time the table1.id and table2.id not same

Comment: you can use simple sql query !

Comment: But some time My ID table1 and 2 different Mohsendid u have other way for me help me please :(

Comment: I use simple query the resulte is : `tbale1 tbale1 tabl1 , table2 table2 table2`

Comment: make your tables reference to each other !

Comment: Hi moshen very thz q na I use your exmple its work for me :D

Answer (score 0):

This answer regardless of table ID in table1 and table2

```
function index()
{
    /**
     * Regardless of any IDs
     */

    # Table1
    $query1  = $this->db->select('image,title')->from('table1')->get();
    $obj1   = $query1->result();
    $offset=-1;
    foreach($obj1 as $row1):
        $offset++;
        $this->combine_with_table2($row1,$offset);
    endforeach;
}

function combine_with_table2($row1,$offset)
{
    $query2  = $this->db->select('image2,title2')->from('table2')->limit(1,$offset)->get();
    $obj2   = $query2->result();
    foreach($obj2 as $row2):
        $output_result = $row1->image.' '.$row1->title.'<br/>'
                        .$row2->image2.' '.$row2->title2.'<br/>';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($output_result);
        echo '</pre>';
    endforeach;
}
```